# typedef emulation in C#

Tags: c#

I have a field variable named uid in a class. The type is int, but I want to open the possibility that I change it long or short.

With C++, typedef is the one for this purpose, but I see C# doesn't have typedef.

Is there a way to mimic typedef in C#?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're trying to alias the type. If so, you can alias it via the [`using` alias directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). You must specify the fully qualified type (the entire namespace) when assigning an alias.

For example:

```
using System;
using MyAlias = System.Int32;

namespace UsingAlias
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyAlias temp = Math.Min(10, 5);
            Console.WriteLine(temp);

            MyAlias result = MyAlias.Parse("42");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. I knew that C# aliases a lot of the more primitive classes (such as string and int), but I didn't know you could create your own! Neat stuff.

Comment: I've typically used this as a technique to work around name conflicts.  E.g., there's a DescriptionAttribute in the MSTest unit test namespace and there's one in various GUI namespaces.  If you want to pull in a GUI namespace for some of the support it gives on your unit tests, a little `using TestDescription = Microsoft.UnitTesting.Whatever.Blah;` can be convenient.

Comment: (Though I do think the original question would be better solved with a `class` or `struct` than a type alias.)

Comment: IMHO this is doesn't mimic a C++ typedef, because the using directive would need to be added to every source file that references it.  In C++ it would be defined in an include file, but C# doesn't support includes.

Answer (score 8):

Try making a `class`.  It's like a typedef on steroids, and you can change the internal representation as much as you want without affecting the interface!

You could even make it a guid!

Answer (score 3):

Make it a struct:

```
struct Uid { public int Value; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulate it in it's own class (or a struct, if more appropriate).

```
public class UID
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Write your methods in terms of your UID class, limiting the exposure to the actual value type to the smallest subset of code necessary.

```
publc class Entity
{
     public UID ID { get; set; }

     public void Foo( UID otherID )
     {
         if (otherID.Value == this.ID.Value)
         {
             ...
         }
     }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a struct with just one field

```
  public struct ID_Type
  {
      public long Id;
  };
```

and use it whereever you need it.

If you have just one class where the ID type is needed, you can also try to make this class a generic class with the UID type being a type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use generics:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
  public T MyField { get; set; } 
}

public class FooInt : Foo<int>
{
}

public class FooShort : Foo<short>
{
}
```

or, just change it later on.

```
/// want an int
public class Foo
{
  public int MyField { get; set; } 
}

/// and just change it later on:
public class Foo
{
  public short MyField { get; set; } 

}
```

Comment: I would actually not recommend generics here. If it is decided to use a different time, it will have to be changed everywhere it is used, instead of just in the "typedef" struct/class. In this case, one may as well just use the original type and avoid the wrapping.

Comment: I'm confused - the point of generics is that the type is a parameter; you'd only have to change it in once place. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the result be the same if you used int and then changed it later on?

Comment: Sure, I guess, if you wanted to find every place it was used and change the declaration of those variables too.

Comment: If there are multiples instances, it should not be a typedef, but a class.

Answer (score 0):

See this , he uses Operator Overloading

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/019a258e-8d50-4a9f-b0ef-8311208ebb6a/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution that helped.

```
    using typedef = System.Int32;

     class MyTypeDef
     {
          typedef ERROR, TRUE=1, FALSE=0;
          public int MyMethod()
          {
              if(this is an error condition)
              {
                 ERROR = TRUE;
              }
              else
              {
                  ERROR = FALSE;
              }
              return ERROR;
          } // end MyMethod
      } // end MyTypeDef
```

Answer (score -2):

> Is there a way to mimic typedef in C#

No

> to solve my problem

What problem?

Comment: -1. Your comment was intended to be funny, but there is definitely a problem here, and telling the world you don't (want to) see it does not help the OP in any ways.

Comment: Actually it wasn't intended to be funny, more to make the OP think more about why he thinks he would need to change the type of his UID to long or short in a modern language like C#.

Comment: In that case, why not post a comment instead of an unhelpful answer?